# AppEngine StdEnv with Python3: How to receive incoming email

Tags: python-3.x, email, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

The current documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/receiving-mail-with-mail-api

looks like it is for python27, otherwise in app.yaml entry should be:

```
- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script: auto (instead of handle_incoming_email.app)
  login: admin
```

I can't find any documentation on how to receive incoming email on GAE StdEnv with Python3. I tried with:

app.yaml

```
runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT incoming_email.app
handlers:
- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script: auto
  login: admin
inbound_services:
- mail
```

requirements.txt

```
ez_setup
gunicorn
google-appengine
```

incoming_email.py

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler
import webapp2

class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):
  """."""
  def receive(self, mail_message):
    """Do things with mail_message"""

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/_ah/mail/', LogSenderHandler)
], debug=True)
```

But when deploying, google-appengine can't build:

```
Error ID: 4646FF8A. Error type: InternalError. Error message: `pip_download_wheels` had stderr output: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-wheel-80z20v2n/google-appengine/

error: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1.
```

google-appengine is needed to import the InboundMailHandler, but looks like google-appengine pip install is for Python 2? Anyone able to receive emails with Python3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python 3 runtime on the App Engine standard environment is significantly different from the Python 2 runtime.

As stated in the [official documentation for the differences between Python 2 and Python 3 on the App Engine standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#mail):

> The Mail service is not available in Python 3. You need to use a third-party mail provider such as SendGrid, Mailgun, or Mailjet to send email. All of these services offer APIs to send email from applications.

In the App Engine Standard Python 3 runtime environment you can find 2 options covered in the official documentation:

- [Mailjet](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/sending-emails-with-mailjet)
- [SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/sending-emails-with-sendgrid)

Both of these mail APIs can receive and parse inbound emails.

Comment: Thanks. I guess Google wants to steer away from the email business, makes sense - I wouldn't want to deal with spam, etc. either... I'm going to use zapier with a webhook (simpler).

Comment: The question was about receiving email, not sending it. Is receiving email possible with python3 app engine? Although it looks like you can receive email with these services. e.g. https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Parse_Webhook/inbound_email.html

Comment: u can receive emails without using any 3rd parties.  Just map the view handlers (create api view) with the corresponding url-mapped emails (/_ah/mail/) and app engine will simply POST those emails on this view. However, it only works in the default service, like if u send an email, from ur python consol, it will be sent to default service

Answer (score 1):

Google has published / migrated the "Google App Engine services SDK for Python 3" in a preview version. "In Python 3, the mail handling functionality is included in the `google.appengine.api.mail` module".
[google cloud mail service for python 3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/services/mail#python-3-flask)

You will need the `appengine-python-standard` library available through pip.
Refere to its git repository: [Git repo of appengine library](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-standard)